# While using firestore (firebase cloud database) getting repetitive data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore data with set limit for load more functionality in tableview while i scroll tableview getting addListener method call in that i check twice, getting duplicate record.

In following code i already print the snapshot which I am getting. Every time I scroll, it print by snapshot id and its data.

Still getting duplicate data. Is there any additional setup from firebase console?

Here my code but there no any fault in code, it's from firebase.

```
func getTasks(){

    // self.tableViewData.reloadDataWithLoader(true)
    let userID = HelperFunction.helper.FetchFromUserDefault(name: kUID)
    let taskRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("tasks")
    let query :Query

    if (self.snapLastkey == "") {
        self.arrayTask = []
        self.arrayKeys = []
        self.arraySelectedTask = []
        query = taskRef.whereField(kUUID, isEqualTo: userID).whereField(kIsCompleted, isEqualTo: false).limit(to: kLimit)
    }else{
        query = taskRef.whereField(kUUID, isEqualTo: userID).whereField(kIsCompleted, isEqualTo: false).limit(to: kLimit).start(afterDocument: self.snapLastDocument!)
    }

    query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

        if(error == nil){

            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
                // The query snapshot has error.
                runOnMainThread {
                    // self.tableViewData.reloadData(withPlaceholderString: "No task found.", with: APP_BLACK_COLOR)
                }
                print("Error retrieving products: \(error.debugDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let lastSnapshot = snapshot.documents.last else {
                // The collection is empty.
                runOnMainThread {
                    self.tableViewData.reloadData(withPlaceholderString: "No task found.", with: APP_BLACK_COLOR)
                    if(self.snapLastkey != "") {
                        self.tableViewData.reloadDataWithLoader(false)
                        self.footerw.endRefreshingWithNoMoreData()

                    }
                }

                return
            }

           // self.snapLastDocument = lastSnapshot

            if (self.arrayTask.count==0) {
                self.arrayTask = []
                self.arrayKeys = []
                self.arraySelectedTask = []
            }




            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach({ (document) in
                print("\(document.document.documentID) => \(document.document.data())")
                let json = JSON(document.document.data())
                self.arrayTask.append(Task.init(json: json))
                self.arraySelectedTask.append(false)
                self.arrayKeys.append(document.document.documentID)
                self.snapLastkey = document.document.documentID as String
                self.snapLastDocument = document.document

            })

            print("\n\n\n\n\n--------arr print---------\n\n")
            for  i in 0..<self.arrayTask.count
            {
                let task = self.arrayTask[i]
                print("arr task Title:",task.title)
            }


            self.tableViewData.reloadData()
            if(self.arrayTask.count==0){
                self.snapLastkey = ""
                self.tableViewData.reloadData(withPlaceholderString: "No task found.", with: APP_BLACK_COLOR)
            }else{
                if Int(snapshot.documents.count) < kLimit{
                    self.snapLastkey = ""
                    self.footerw.endRefreshingWithNoMoreData()
                }
                else{
                    self.footerw.endRefreshing()
                }

            }
            print(self.arrayTask)

        }else{
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            self.tableViewData.reloadData(withPlaceholderString: "Try again.", with: APP_BLACK_COLOR)
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

It just **indexing issue**.I found it in log.So in log I got the link for creating index on firebase index section.I have been created the new index which needed and my data is coming exactly that I want.